# Any way to simplify permission checks?

Tags: android, optimization, permissions

I am currently working with permissions in Android Studio.

I've checked how the tutorial does it, and I've seen that it's really obnoxious and long. The current code is this:

```
    String[] InternetPermission = new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET};
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ViewingWindow.this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(ViewingWindow.this,
                Manifest.permission.INTERNET)) {
            InternetExplanation();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ViewingWindow.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_INTERNET);
        }

    }

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_INTERNET: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                this.finishAffinity();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is obviously rather long for a single permission check in my opinion. I've always wondered why the entire permission check isn't a simple if statement check.

Is there a reason for permission checks to be this long? If not, is there a way to try and optimise it?

Comment: You must refer this : https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In API 23 Or `Android 6.0` we have to asked permission from user and you better know it already.

If user need single permission then you have to ask from user for so

1. First you check weather app already have the permission so `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ViewingWindow.this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET)` this line will came up.
2. If app dont have then we request so `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ViewingWindow.this,
                   new String[]{Manifest.permission.INTERNET},
                   MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_INTERNET);` this line came up.
3. finally lastly you have callback to check weather user granted/Rejected permission we receptively we create next behavior so `public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
   switch (requestCode) {
       case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_INTERNET: {
           // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
           if (grantResults.length > 0
                   && grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
               this.finishAffinity();
           }
       }
   }`

So you dont have write all code for single permission everytime so you just write it once and use OOPs power/features.

Comment: Urgh, that sucks. Well then I'll just have do get through it. Thanks for answering though!